# Using JSR-303 validator instead of Spring Validator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a very naive conceptual question here for clarification. In my app I'm currently using JSR 303 Hibernate Validator for validating the domain model with @NotBlank and @NotNull annotations, like checking username, password etc.

```
public class Admin {

  private Long id;
  @NotBlank(message = "Username should not be null")
  private String username;
  @NotBlank(message = "Username should not be null")
  private String password;
  ...
```

But for validating the domain logic like existing username, I'm still using Spring's Validator interface

```
@Component
public class AdminValidator implements Validator {
  ...
  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    Admin admin = (Admin) target;
    if (usernameAlradyExist())){
        errors.rejectValue("username", null, "This user already exist's in the system.");
    }

}
```

In the controller I'm using both

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("admin") Admin admin, BindingResult bindingResult,) {
    validator.validate(admin, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return REGISTER_ADMIN.getViewName();

    }
```

Is it possible just to use Hibernate Validator and not at all use Spring Validator for validating domain logic?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, You can use JSR validation for your domain logic validation. You need to define custom constraint annotations and define your domain logic validation inside it.
Like
Defining custom constraint annotation `UserExistsConstraint`

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy=UserExistsConstraintValidator.class)

public @interface UserExistsConstraint {
 String message() default "This user already exist's in the system.";
 Class<!--?-->[] groups() default {};
 Class<!--? extends Payload-->[] payload() default {};
}
```

Defining validator for custom annotation.

```
public class UserExistsConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserExistsConstraint, object=""> {

 @Override
 public void initialize(UserExistsConstraint constraint) {

 }

 @Override
 public boolean isValid(Object target, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
   if (usernameAlradyExist())
   {    
     return false;
   }
   else
   {
     return true; 
   }    
 }
}
```

Using custom annotation

```
public class Admin {

  private Long id;
  @NotBlank(message = "Username should not be null")
  @UserExistsConstraint
  private String username;
  @NotBlank(message = "Username should not be null")
  private String password;
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are configuring Spring MVC with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` then it will automatically configure a [JSR 303 validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator) if some JSR 303 validator impl(hibernate-validator for eg) is present in the classpath.

Or if you explicitly want to configure the validator, you can do this:

```
<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

This again would look for a JSR 303 implementation and use that as the validator.

You can default it to validate any @Valid form object by registering a global validator this way:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>
```

Comment: I think OP asking for how to implement business logic validation in JSR like we define in spring validation. IMHO its about defining custom annotation in JSR-303 while your answer talks about configuring and using JSR validation. Please correct me if I am making any wrong assumption.